# Hide columns in various sheets in Google Sheets on open

Tags: google-sheets

I have a few scripts which, individually, all work. However I am unable to get them to all run on opening the sheet.  At the moment, only the first script (hideColumn) runs on opening the sheet.  The others all work when called directly from the menu I managed to create.

```
function onOpen() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // create menu
  var menu = [{name: "Hide Overview Columns", functionName: "hideColumn"},
              {name: "Hide Rebalancing Columns", functionName: "hideColumn2"},
              {name: "Add/Hide Dividend Data for Chart", functionName: "hideColumn3"}];

  // add to menu
  ss.addMenu("Check", menu);

  // execute function
  function hideColumn(){

function hideColumn(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Overview");

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;

  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // itterate through columns
  for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
     if(data.getCell(1, i).getValue() == 'HIDE') {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
     }
  }
}


  function hideColumn2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Rebalancing");

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;

  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // itterate through columns
  for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
     if(data.getCell(2, i).getValue() == 'HIDE') {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
     }
  }
}

  function showColumn3() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dividends - Calculations");

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn();

  // show all columns
  sheet.showColumns(1, lastCol);
}


  function hideColumn3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dividends - Calculations");

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;

  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // itterate through columns
  for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
     if(data.getCell(1, i).getValue() == 'HIDE') {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
     }
  }
  }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can help but won't code for you unless you showed us you tried!
Your best option is to have a look at the [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) documentation.

Here are the pages you need to check to do your script (you'll see it's well explained)

- [Create a menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Hide a column](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideColumn(Range))
- [Get the content of a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
- [Create a loop to check several cell one by one in JS (Mozilla Doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)